# Convergence in distribution of constrained MLE?

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, convergence

Consider a sample of i.i.d. random variables $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^N$ with $X_i$ distributed as $N(\mu,1)$.

The MLE estimator of $\mu$ subject to $\mu \geq 0$ is $\mu_{mle, constrained}=\max \{0,\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\}$.

I want to show that $\mu_{mle, constrained}$ converges in distribution to $Z$ if $\mu>0$ and to $max(0,Z)$ if $\mu=0$ where $Z$ is distributed as a $N(0,1)$. Any help?

Comment: I'm not very well-versed in asymptotics, but would it make sense to derive the MLE with an indicator $I_{x\geq0}(x)$ in lieu of a constraint? I get that these will ultimately lead to the same result, but perhaps it makes the mechanics easier when proving this?